# Partitioning the data into equal number of records for each group in spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have 1 month of data and each day has data of size which falls in the range of 10 to 100GB. We will be writing this data set in a partitioned manner. Here in our case, we have DATE parameter using which we will be partitioning the data in the data frame (partition("DATE")). And we also apply repartition to this data frame to create single or multiple files. If we repartition to 1, it creates 1 file for each partition. If we set to 5 it creates 5 partition files and is good.

But what we are trying here is, we want to make sure is each group (partitioned data of date) is created with equal size files (either through a number of records or sizes of files).

We have used spark data frame option "maxRecordsPerFile" and set to 10Million records. And this is working as expected. for 10 days of data, if I am doing this in one go, it is eating up the execution time, as it is collecting all 10 days of data and trying to do some distribution.

If I don't set this parameter and if I don't set repartition to 1, then this activity is completing in 5 minutes, but if I just set partition("DATE") and maxRecrodsPerFile option it is taking almost an hour.

Looking forward to some help on this!

~Krish

Comment: I have a few questions:

(a). Where are you storing the data? Hive/Kudu/Mongo/S3?
(b). Since you want to store data in partitioned manner why aren't partitioning the table with the "Date". 

Your problem is not while processing but while dumping the output correct?

Comment: We store data in HDFS, and we have partitioning as well on date. I am looking for balancing the execution with records per file option, the data frame has option for this in the form of maxRecordsPerFile. This is working but it has performance hit. Looks like you have missed the core point that I am looking for and is records per file option.